# Modifying RPC context data from an interceptor?

Tags: typescript, apache-kafka, nestjs

It is possible to modify the request payload of a HTTP-based context (e.g. [this method](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/337#issuecomment-396073378)), but is there a way to modify the payload of an RPC-based context?

In my case, my NestJS setup is a microservice listening to a specific Kafka topic (`Customer`). The messages are encoded using Avro, so I'm trying to create an interceptor to globally decode every message from Kafka.

```
// inside intercept function
const rpcContext = context.switchToRpc().getContext();
const kafkaMessageBuffer: Buffer = context.switchToRpc().getData();
const decodedMessage = await this.schemaRegistry.decode(kafkaMessageBuffer);

// My attempt to replace the value (which is a buffer) with the decoded data
rpcContext.args[0]['value'] = decodedMessage;
```

This doesn't work because `args` [is a protected property](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/v9.4.2/packages/microservices/ctx-host/base-rpc.context.ts#L2) so I couldn't modify it.

What are the other alternative ways I could globally decode all Kafka messages?

Other alternatives that I could think of:

- Create a custom pipe to transform the data in the controller:

  - `@Payload(AvroTransformPipe) message: CustomerMessage`
- Manually decode the message in the controller before passing the decoded message to services

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a [Global Pipe](https://docs.nestjs.com/pipes#global-scoped-pipes).

```js
transform(value: any, metadata: ArgumentMetadata): any {
  if (metadata.type !== 'body') {
    return value;
  }

  return value instanceof Buffer ? this.schemaRegistry.decode(value) : null;
}
```

This solution is not perfect because it will apply to every decorator (hence the `metadata.type` check), and I'm not sure how to target it to a specific decorator (in my case I only want to target `@Payload()`). It could also be problematic if the application is a Hybrid application with HTTP endpoints.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. My solution was in the global interceptor, execute dynamically de method without use next.handle():

```
const rpcHost: RpcArgumentsHost = context.switchToRpc();
const dataWrapper = rpcHost.getData();
const user = dataWrapper.user;
const data = dataWrapper.data;

const instance = app.get(context.getClass());

const resultPromise: Promise<any> =
  instance[context.getHandler().name](data);

return from(resultPromise);
```